# react-router 6 Navigate to using params

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

In v5 i have such structure

```
{
    path: '/someurl/:id',
    exact: true,
    render: ({ params }) => (<Redirect to={`/someurl/extraurl/${params.id}`} />),
}
```

How to refactor this to V6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-router-dom` v6 no longer has route props, so you'll need to create a new component to gather the "props", or `match.params` in this case, and render the redirect as a `Navigate` component.

```
const MyRedirect = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Navigate to={`/someurl/extraurl/${id}`} replace />;
};
```

...

```
{
  path: '/someurl/:id',
  element: <MyRedirect />,
}
```

...

```
<Route path={obj.path} element={obj.element} />
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will work but I'll add my solution too, since it's a bit more dynamic. You can set up a function component that will make use of the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) hook and the [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#generatepath) function so your intended destination gets the params from the initial route (whatever they may be):

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { generatePath, Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IProps {
    to: string;
    replace?: boolean;
    state?: any;
}

const Redirect: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ to, replace, state }) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const redirectWithParams = generatePath(to, params);

    return (
        <Navigate to={redirectWithParams} replace={replace} state={state} />
    );
};

export default Redirect;
```

Using this should work with your first example (and any other routes / redirects with dynamic params).